# Hibernate @ManyToMany doesn't save to third table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

User has roles and and has Set roles:

Class User

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User extends BaseEntity {

        @Column(name = "username")
        private String username;

        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;

        @Transient
        private String confirmPassword;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
        private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getConfirmPassword() {
            return confirmPassword;
        }

        public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
            this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
        }

        public Set<Role> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User{" +
                    "username='" + username + '\'' +
                    ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                    ", confirmPassword='" + confirmPassword + '\'' +
                    ", roles=" + roles +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Class Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role extends NamedEntity {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Tables

```
-- Table: users
CREATE TABLE users (
  id       INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- Table: roles
CREATE TABLE roles (
  id   INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- Table for mapping user and roles: user_roles
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  role_id INT NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id),

  UNIQUE (user_id, role_id)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Repository classes:

JpaUserRepositoryImpl

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JpaUserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public void registerUser(User user) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        session.close();

    }

    public User findUserByUsername(String username) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();

        User user;
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT user FROM User user WHERE user.username LIKE :username");
        query.setParameter("username", username + "%");
        user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
        session.close();
        return user;
    }

    public User findUserById(Long id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        User user = session.get(User.class, id);
        session.close();

        return user;
    }
}
```

JpaRoleRepositoryImpl

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JpaRoleRepositoryImpl implements RoleRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Role findRoleById(Long id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Role role = session.get(Role.class, id);
        session.close();
        return role;
    }

    public Role findRoleByName(String name) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT role FROM Role role WHERE role.name =:name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        Role role = (Role) query.getSingleResult();
        session.close();
        return role;
    }
}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    JpaUserRepositoryImpl userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleServiceImpl roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


    public void registerUser(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(roleRepository.findRoleById(1L));
        user.setRoles(roles);
        System.out.println(user);
        userRepository.registerUser(user);
    }

    public User findUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
        return user;
    }

    public User findUserById(Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findUserById(id);
        return user;
    }
}
```

After creating new user I have it in table users, but no changes in table user_roles.
Can't understand why.
Any ideas?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to Cascade the insert operation of `user` to `User_roles` table, but you haven't provided `cascade` strategy in the mapping.

By default the cascade strategy is "none" i.e. no changes will be propagated to the child tables.

Try applying cascade option in the mapping and it should work.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

I have used CAscadeType.ALL but you can restrict it to only insertion or update or delete or any combination.

Comment: Unfortunately, problem not here.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? share the SQLs being executed in the DB by enabling show_sql and format_sql options of hibernate